# Split a string into smaller strings with conditions

Tags: python

I have a string that is constantly getting longer for each iteration (moves in a game). I want to print this string to my window and the window space is 75 characters in a row, then I need to switch line.

Condition: The list contains the move numbers and corresponding moves for each side:

```
my_str = '1.move movee 2.mov moveee 3.mo mover'
```

The split can't be in the middle of a move so it needs to happen between the moves:

```
my_str1 = '1.move movee 2.mov moveee'
my_str2 = '3.mo mover'
```

Is there a nice way of doing this without lots and lots of loops and if statements?

Comment: What is the logic for splitting?

Comment: Do you have control over defining and building up this string?  I think the best answer is to not create the string in the first place, but create a list instead.  You could then much more easily perform the kind of formatting you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that works by first extracting each move (might be valuable to you in itself) and then prints the list of moves with line length logic:

```
import re

my_str = '1.move movee 2.mov moveee 3.mo mover 4.move movee 5.mov moveee 6.mo mover 7.move movee 8.mov moveee 9.mo mover 10.move movee 11.mov moveee 12.mo mover 13.move movee 14.mov moveee 15.mo mover'

moves = re.findall(r"\S+\s+\S+", my_str)

line = ''
for move in moves:
    if len(line) + len(move) + 1 > 75:
        print(line)
        line = move
    elif line:
        line += ' ' + move
    else:
        line = move
if (line):
    print(line)
```

Result:

```
1.move movee 2.mov moveee 3.mo mover 4.move movee 5.mov moveee 6.mo mover
7.move movee 8.mov moveee 9.mo mover 10.move movee 11.mov moveee
12.mo mover 13.move movee 14.mov moveee 15.mo mover
```

Comment: That is a neat function that I did not know of! Thank you for the answer Steve.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use the `end` parameter of the `print` function:

```
my_str = '1.move movee 2.mov moveee 3.mo mover'

count = 0
length = len(my_str)

for i, v in enumerate(my_str):
    if i - 1 < length :
        if count >= 75 and my_str[i + 1].isdigit():
            count = 0
            s = '\n'
        else:
            count += 1
            s = ''
    print(v, end=s)
```

With `end=''` as a `print` parameter, when you proceed to print again, the output will be printed on the same line.

```
if count >= 75 and i == ' ':
```

tells python when to switch a line; when the number of characters reach `75`, and the current character needs to be a `' '` so to not cut a move.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing your moves in a [list](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp).

Adding a move:

```
moves.append("move movee")
```

Reading moves:

```
moves[0] # First move
moves[1] # Second move
moves[-1] # Last move
moves[-2] # Second to last move
```

Iterating through moves:

```
for move in moves:
    print(move)
```

Here is a [function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp) that will print your moves:

```
moves = ["nassssssssssss ssssss sssssssssssssss", "nasdasdasda sdasdas", "eas dasdasdasd", "easdasdasda sdasdsad", "sasda dsasdasd"]

def formatMoves(moves, screenwidth=75):
    out = ""
    for i in range(len(moves)):
        move = moves[i]

        if len(out) == 0 or len(out.split("\n")[-1]) == 0:
            # Start a new line
            out += f"{str(i+1)}.{move}"
        
        elif len(out.split("\n")[-1]) + len(str(i+1)) + 2 + len(move) <= screenwidth:
            # Continue a line
            out += f" {str(i+1)}.{move}"
            
        else:
            # Start a new line
            out += f"\n{str(i+1)}.{move}"
    return out

print("-"*75)
print(formatMoves(moves))
```

Output (the first line just shows it is 75 chars long):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1.nassssssssssss ssssss sssssssssssssss 2.nasdasdasda sdasdas
3.eas dasdasdasd 4.easdasdasda sdasdsad 5.sasda dsasdasd
```